# How to dismis Viewcontroller (popup) by pressing button inside my popup viewcontroller and also touch any where outside of viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, popup

I have one viewcontroler with one button.When i press that one pop up viewcontroller will show up.And when i touch anywhere outside it dismiss the viewcontroller .And return to my main viewcontroller.

**Note**

I used my popup through one viewcontroller and i use identifier name .Then i show pop up using that storyboard identifier and declared in my `viewcontroller.m` in `btnSelectDatePressed`

**Needed**

in that pop up view controller i have one button when user press also it should dismiss the viewcontroller and should return to my main viewcontroller.My example image is like this [sample image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xoyfm7j3dwvcxfx/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2024-Sep-2015%2011.51.32%20am.png?dl=0)

This is my `viewcontroller.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+ENPopUp.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
- (IBAction)btnSelectDatePressed:(id)sender
{

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopUp"];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 309.0f, 531.0f);
    [self presentPopUpViewController:vc];

}
```

This is my popup method declared in `#import "UIViewController+ENPopUp.h"`

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface UIViewController (ENPopUp)

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *en_popupViewController;
    - (void)presentPopUpViewController:(UIViewController *)popupViewController;
    - (void)presentPopUpViewController:(UIViewController *)popupViewController completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock;
    - (void)dismissPopUpViewController;
    - (void)dismissPopUpViewControllerWithcompletion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock;
    //- (IBAction)disMe:(id)sender;

    @end


This is my popup method declared in `#import "UIViewController+ENPopUp.m"`

#import "UIViewController+ENPopUp.h"
#import "JWBlurView.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void * ENPopupViewControllerPropertyKey = &ENPopupViewControllerPropertyKey;

static CGFloat const kAnimationDuration = .4f;
static CGFloat const kRotationAngle = 70.f;

static NSInteger const kENPopUpOverlayViewTag   = 351301;
static NSInteger const kENPopUpViewTag          = 351302;
static NSInteger const kENPopUpBluredViewTag    = 351303;

@implementation UIViewController (ENPopUp)

#pragma mark - Public Methods
- (void)presentPopUpViewController:(UIViewController *)popupViewController
{
    [self presentPopUpViewController:popupViewController completion:nil];
}

- (void)presentPopUpViewController:(UIViewController *)popupViewController completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    self.en_popupViewController = popupViewController;
    [self presentPopUpView:popupViewController.view completion:completionBlock];
}





- (void)dismissPopUpViewController
{
    [self dismissPopUpViewControllerWithcompletion:nil];
}

- (void)dismissPopUpViewControllerWithcompletion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    UIView *sourceView = [self topView];
    JWBlurView *blurView = (JWBlurView *)[sourceView viewWithTag:kENPopUpBluredViewTag];
    UIView *popupView = [sourceView viewWithTag:kENPopUpViewTag];
    UIView *overlayView = [sourceView viewWithTag:kENPopUpOverlayViewTag];
    [self performDismissAnimationInSourceView:sourceView withBlurView:blurView popupView:popupView overlayView:overlayView completion:completionBlock];
}










//- (IBAction)disMe:(id)sender {
   // UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Pop"];

  //  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
//}


#pragma mark - Getters & Setters
- (UIViewController *)en_popupViewController
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, ENPopupViewControllerPropertyKey);
}

- (void)setEn_popupViewController:(UIViewController *)en_popupViewController
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, ENPopupViewControllerPropertyKey, en_popupViewController, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

}

#pragma mark - View Handling
- (void)presentPopUpView:(UIView *)popUpView completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    UIView *sourceView = [self topView];
    // Check if source view controller is not in destination
    if ([sourceView.subviews containsObject:popUpView]) return;

    // Add overlay
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sourceView.bounds];
    overlayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    overlayView.tag = kENPopUpOverlayViewTag;
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add Blured View
    JWBlurView *bluredView = [[JWBlurView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayView.bounds];
    bluredView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    bluredView.tag = kENPopUpBluredViewTag;
    [bluredView setBlurAlpha:.0f];
    [bluredView setAlpha:.0f];
    [bluredView setBlurColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    bluredView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [overlayView addSubview:bluredView];

    // Make the background clickable
    UIButton * dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    dismissButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    dismissButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dismissButton.frame = sourceView.bounds;
    [overlayView addSubview:dismissButton];

    [dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPopUpViewController)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Customize popUpView
    popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.5f;
    popUpView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    popUpView.layer.zPosition = 99;
    popUpView.tag = kENPopUpViewTag;
    popUpView.center = overlayView.center;
    [popUpView setNeedsLayout];
    [popUpView setNeedsDisplay];

    [overlayView addSubview:popUpView];
    [sourceView addSubview:overlayView];

    [self setAnimationStateFrom:popUpView];
    [self performAppearAnimationWithBlurView:bluredView popupView:popUpView completion:completionBlock];
}



#pragma mark - Animation
- (void)setAnimationStateFrom:(UIView *)view
{
    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    layer.transform = [self transform3d];
}

- (CATransform3D)transform3d
{
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, 200.f, 0);
    transform.m34 = 1.0/800.0;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, kRotationAngle*M_PI/180.f, 1.f, .0f, .0f);
    CATransform3D scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(.7f, .7f, .7f);
    return CATransform3DConcat(transform, scale);
}

- (void)performAppearAnimationWithBlurView:(JWBlurView *)blurView popupView:(UIView *)popupView completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{

    CATransform3D transform;
    transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                     animations:^ {
                         [self.en_popupViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
                         [blurView setAlpha:1.f];
                         popupView.layer.transform = transform;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.en_popupViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
                         if (completionBlock != nil) {
                             completionBlock();
                         }
                     }];
}


- (void)performDismissAnimationInSourceView:(UIView *)sourceView
                               withBlurView:(JWBlurView *)blurView
                                  popupView:(UIView *)popupView
                                overlayView:(UIView *)overlayView
                                 completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    CATransform3D transform = [self transform3d];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                     animations:^ {
                         [self.en_popupViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
                         [blurView setAlpha:0.f];
                         popupView.layer.transform = transform;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [popupView removeFromSuperview];
                         [blurView  removeFromSuperview];
                         [overlayView  removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.en_popupViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
                         self.en_popupViewController = nil;
                         if (completionBlock != nil) {
                             completionBlock();
                         }
                     }];
}

#pragma mark - Getters

- (UIView*)topView {
    UIViewController *recentView = self;
    while (recentView.parentViewController != nil) {
        recentView = recentView.parentViewController;
    }
    return recentView.view;
}


@end
```

I am beginner in ios.Some one please give some solution for my problem.Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code of `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` for have a visible button.

In code existe a button with screen size for dismiss view.  I changed this button and now he is visible.

In `presentPopUpView` `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` where have this comment " // Make the background clickable" I change the code to this:

```
CGFloat buttonSize = 10;

UIButton * dismissButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
dismissButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
dismissButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (buttonSize/2),(self.view.frame.size.height/2) + (self.view.frame.size.height/4) , buttonSize, buttonSize);

[overlayView addSubview:dismissButton];

[dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPopUpViewController)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This create a red button 10x10 like in figure:

[image]

Now, you can change the color and the size of button for what you want.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: i have tried your code.Its work well to create a button like your image shown.But what  i need is when i press that button my pop up should go off and return to my main viewcontroller. And also when i click some where outside in my popup view it should dismiss and return yo my viewcontroller.Both should work for dismiss my popup

Comment: I had not realized that part. For do this you can use delegates. And create a method in your viewController to pop to first viewController. And In  file `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` in `dismissPopUpViewController` call this delegate method. Is it you want?

Comment: sorry i am new to ios .i am not much familiar with these concepts. I need to dismisspopup when i touch outside some where and also when i press my button like you create

Comment: You just need dismiss popup when you touch in button and outside? It is more easy :D. On my answer I say to change a block of code. For do what you want just need not change the code but add the my code (you need change button name). With this you have a invisible button with screen size, and another small button (the red button). It is you want?

Comment: Yes you are right .I have check your answer its working well for pop up viewcontroller size (270 X 230).But i used (273 X 388) pop up view.that red button hides .that red button went behind my pop up.is there any size does i need to change in your solution code

Comment: yes i got solution for that frame size.Thanks alot .Really yu helped me